# Truly Strongly Typed Type Providers

Tags: f#, strong-typing, type-providers

I don't get how to provide strongly typed types through type provider.
All the exemples I see have the same type as a result, independently of the input.

MiniCsvTypeProvider provides only double.
RegexTypeProvider provides only matches.

Is it possible to provide properties of different **types depending** on a parameter supplied to the type provider ?

```
    if somevariable then 
        proptype = typeof<int>
    else
        proptype = typeof<string>

    let staticProp = ProvidedProperty(propertyName = "property", 
                                      propertyType = propType, 
                                      GetterCode= (fun [arg] -> <@@ %%arg :?> propType @@>))
```

Comment: or maybe I need to dynamically create an union type and for every item, create one. not so easy.

Comment: I think one has to go through a runtime 'dynamic cast'

Comment: (all this sh*t would go away with a staged runtime. just ranting)

Comment: No luck with runtime dynamic cast, as lambda calls are not supported in let transQuotationToCodeViaLinq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's easy to provide different types depending on the input.  As a very simple example, you could do something like:

```
let propType, propValue =
    if somevariable then
        typeof<int>, <@@ 1 @@>
    else
        typeof<string>, <@@ "test" @@>

let prop = ProvidedProperty("property", propType, GetterCode = fun [_] -> propValue)
```

To expand this along the lines you're suggesting, you could define the entire getter in the conditional:

```
let propType, propGetter =
    if somevariable then
        typeof<int>, fun [arg] -> <@@ %%arg : int @@>
    else
        typeof<string>, fun [arg] -> <@@ %%arg : string @@>

let prop = ProvidedProperty("property", propType, GetterCode = fun [_] -> propValue)
```

However, note that you then need to ensure that the representation that you call the property on is an `int` or `string` respectively.  Also note that in contrast to your chosen naming (`staticProp`), these are not static properties, since you're passing a receiver (`arg`) to the getter and haven't marked the `ProvidedProperty` static.

Comment: Thank you. I need to test this indeed.